# MySQL: query taking more than 30 seconds to execute

Tags: mysql

I'm just figuring out how to do more complex queries within MySQL and one of the queries that I have created is taking a lot longer than I would have expected (~30s), and I'm not sure how I can optimize the query to run more efficiently.  My query is meant to get all customers that have currently advertised with us before but haven't signed up to advertise in the past 4 months for the stores that we have currently listed.

My archive schema looks something like this:

```
|CustomerID | StoreID | DateAdvertised |
|1          | Store1  | 11/01/2020     |
|2          | Store2  | 06/01/2020     |
|1          | Store3  | 08/01/2020     |
.           .         .                .
.           .         .                .
```

My customer schema looks something like this:

```
|CustomerID | Name  |  Email       | LastRan    | DNC | IsStore |
|1          | Bob   | bob@email.com| 2020-11-01 | 1   | 0       |
|2          | Joe   | joe@email.com| 2020-06-01 | 0   | 0       |
.           .       .              .
.           .       .              .
```

My stores schema looks something like this:

```
|StoreID  | Address      |  Working  |
|Store1   | some address | 1         |
|Store2   | some address | 0         |
|Store3   | some address | 1         |
.         .              .           .
.         .              .           .
```

In my query I have to get the customers email, customers name, and store address along with the other archive data listed.  I created a query that includes 3 joins on the 3 tables so that I can get the data I need from each one, and I'm starting to think that this is what's causing my query to run this slow.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    s.StoreID,
    s.Address,
    c.Name,
    c.CustomerID,
    c.LastRan,
    c.Email
FROM
    Archives a
        JOIN
    Customers c
        JOIN
    Stores s ON (a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        AND a.StoreID = s.StoreID
        AND s.Working = '1')
WHERE
    c.DNC = '0' AND c.IsStore = '0'
        AND c.LastRan != ''
        AND c.LastRan != 'N/A'
        AND STR_TO_DATE(c.LastRan, '%m/%d/%Y') < '2020-08-01'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
HAVING Email != '';
```

I tried removing the subquery that this query originally had to not include duplicate CustomerID values but I figured that using `group by` would make it a little faster, but it didn't make much of a difference.  I also tried removing some other checks that I thought were unnecessary, but these didn't make a difference either.  If anyone has any suggestions on how I can optimize my query to be more efficient that would be great.  TIA!

**EDIT**

EXPLAIN

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Just by adding Indexes to CustomerID and StoreID in both my archive and customers schema seems to run the query much faster.

Comment: you need to add a EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query and a create table of all tables  to see the existing indexes for such a question

Comment: @nbk  Ok I will see what I can pull

Comment: Your DateAdvertised column should be date type and not string. Don' t use string to store dates

Comment: @nacho would this cause a reduction in performance?

Comment: Yea, first EXPLAIN ANALYZE to debug.
Add indexes to columns you use to search, then you can look at query

Comment: edited question with the explain from the select statement

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements for the tables and any indexes on them.

Comment: While the comment from @nacho is true, I would also note then when you store a date in a string (for whatever good reason you might have), you should always use the format `YYYYMMDD`, because this allows sorting without the conversion to date.

Comment: str_to_date and the not equals seem to be issues at a glance.

Comment: @Luuk the archives table I have is the only table that is like that in terms of how the date is formatted.  I wasn't the one who set it up that way unfortunately.

Comment: @Randy what would you do to look for fields that have blank values in them that aren't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't store `LastRan` as a string; store it as a `DATE` or `DATETIME`.  That eliminates the un-sargeable function call, hence will allow the following index to help:
- `INDEX(DNC, IsStore, LastRan)`
- If there is only one row in `c` for each `CustomerID`, then there is no advantage in putting `email != ''` in `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.
- Use `ON` for saying how tables are related; use `WHERE` for filtering.  That is, move `AND s.Working = '1'` from `ON` to `WHERE`.
- Get rid of the JOIN to `Archives`; it seems to be useless.
- If there is only one row per Customer, get rid of the unnecessary `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

An "ON" condition needs to be added when joining to the Customers Table

```
JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
```

Comment: good catch.. this might be forcing it to cross join

Comment: instead of doing both in the one ```ON``` clause should I be doing them seperately?

Comment: Yes, you need an ON clause for each JOIN. The EXPLAIN will show that it's not using an index otherwise. Without an ON clause it's matching every row of the JOIN table to every row of the current result set.

Answer (score 0):

Without schema changes, the only thing which will speed up this query is to move the Email != '' predicate inside the 'where' clause (which is where it should have been in the first place).

All your non-join predicates are in the Customers table - which *suggests* that indexes on these might improve performance - but that depends on your data distribution. Further, just throwing indexes in to solve the performance of a specific query can be very counter-productive.